# Create a drop down menu based on a group

Tags: sharepoint-online, groups, sharepoint-calendar, person-or-group

I have a group called Onshore Management and I want their names to populate a drop down menu so the appropriate person can be selected on a calendar event.

Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 0):

**OOTB Solution**:

Instead of using a choice/dropdown field you can use the `person or group` field and set its source to particular group from column settings like given in below image:

[image]

Follow below steps:

1. Go to List Settings.
2. Go to **Columns** section and click on **Create column**.
3. Give a name to column and select its data type to **Person or Group**.
4. Set **Allow selection of** to **People Only**.
5. Set **Choose from** to **SharePoint Group**.
6. Select your SharePoint Group (Onshore Management) from dropdown below it.
7. Click **OK**.